# Fetching sms message sent with notify api

Tags: twilio, sms, twilio-api

I use [Twilio Notify Api](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/quickstart/sms?code-sample=code-send-sms-notification-to-a-number-2&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=5.x#send-an-sms-notification) to send sms messages to multiple recipients with a single call like this:

```
var notification = NotificationResource.Create(serviceSid,
    toBinding: new List<string> { "{\"binding_type\":\"sms\",\"address\":\"+1234\"}", 
    "{\"binding_type\":\"sms\",\"address\":\"+12345\"}","{\"binding_type\":\"sms\",\"address\":\"+123456\"}"},
    sms: new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "from", "Test" } },deliveryCallbackUrl: "https://bd3c0482bdc2.ngrok.io",
    body: "Knok-Knok! This is your first Notify SMS");
```

This works fine when there is no issue delivering the message but if delivery fails when the webhook gets hit it doesn't include the **to** number that failed the message to be delivered.

I also tried retrieving the message using the sid that is included in the webhook but it results in http error 404:

> The requested resource
>   /2010-04-01/Accounts/AC...../Messages/SM52f9b0.....json was not found

So is there any way to get the to number that the delivery failed to when using twilio notify api?

Comment: Hello @Giorgi. Did you manage to solve this? I'm stuck in the exact same situation.